# Is it possible to Navigate back in Salesforce1 after opening pdf file in SalesForce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, file-processing

We have developed a VisualForce page and have link to a PDF file and are rending that in SalesForce1 app.( VisualForce has only HTML5 + Remoting Functions). Its working fine in SalesForce1 app and able to open the PDF file also. But there is no way to go back to the page where we clicked this link.
This is the behavior in iPhone5, iPad.

Is there any other way to achieve that? Thank you in advance.

Thanks,
Shrivaths

Comment: Any suggestions please? Thanks

Comment: hi, do you have any news on this? thx